# Return entire dms data from boto3 using marker/pagination

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

Boto3 lib allows retrieving various metadata for AWS' services. Some of the methods use pagination marker to harvest entire data.

I have an issue with retrieving list of all DMS tasks under my account. How to pass retried marker to get the data in one run?

```
import boto3
import sys

dms = boto3.client('dms')
replication_tasks = dms.describe_replication_tasks(
    MaxRecords=100,
    Marker='',
    WithoutSettings=True) 

dictr = replication_tasks['ReplicationTasks'][0]
lst = replication_tasks['ReplicationTasks']
marker = replication_tasks['Marker']
if marker:
    print(lst)
    next_set = dms.describe_replication_tasks(MaxRecords=100, Marker=marker, WithoutSettings=True)
    lst.append(next_set)
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume something like this.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('dms')

paginator = client.get_paginator('describe_replication_tasks')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate(
    WithoutSettings=True,
)

for response in response_iterator:
    print(response)
```